# Effective long text drawing in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uitableview

I'm fetching an array of comments, which I need to display in a tableView.

The tableView has custom cells for displaying content. The problem is that comments text can vary in its length and I'm facing a serious memory growth while scrolling the tableView.

Several approaches I've tried to display the text:

- UILabel;
- UITextView;
- drawing on a custom view;

Besides the tableView seems to not be dequeueing my custom cells, so the memory keeps growing while the tableView is being scrolled (my cells are now having 1.5К symbols of text)

[image]

Cells are created like this, so nothing special

```
- (UITableViewCell*)            tableView: (UITableView*) tableView
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
     [tableView registerClass: [CommentCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: kCommentCellId];

     CommentCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: kCommentCellId
                                                         forIndexPath: indexPath];

     Comment* comment = [self.comments objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

     cell.comment = comment;

     return cell;
}
```

Custom setter for comment property

```
- (void) setComment: (Comment*) aComment
{
    self.commentLabel.text = aComment.comment;

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Adding comment label inside the cell

```
- (id) initWithStyle: (UITableViewCellStyle) style
 reuseIdentifier: (NSString*) reuseIdentifier
{
   self = [super initWithStyle: style reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier];

   if (self)
   {
        // Comment label
        //
        self.commentLabel = [UILabel new];

        self.commentLabel.textColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.21f green: 0.21f blue: 0.21f alpha: 1.00f];
        self.commentLabel.font          = [UIFont helveticaNeueRegularOfSize: 13.33f];
        self.commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.commentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

        [self.contentView addSubview: self.commentLabel];
    }

    return self;
 }
```

Comment: Not enough information. Post your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @DuncanC, I've added the code for cell creation

Comment: Still not enough information. Post your **entire** cellForRowAtIndexPath method, from declaration to the closing bracket.

Comment: @DuncanC, please view my edits

Comment: first thing first: log inside your cell's init and see how many cells are actually being created over the lifetime of the app; there should be only about 10

Comment: @matt, nope, the cells are somehow created for each text entry. Very strange, cause nothing seems to cause a retain cycle or smth.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You are doing something wrong, but probably not in any code you are showing. You must have more code, like the code that calculates the cell heights. Perhaps the problem is there. You should easily be able to use Instruments to track down the leak; it shows you the retains/releases on every object.

Comment: Also you can download the [code from my book](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p424variableHeights/ch21p722variableHeights/RootViewController.m) showing how to make cells consisting of a label whose height varies from row to row. It doesn't leak, so imitate what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is presumably that you are wrongly retaining and never releasing cell objects in code you are not showing, such as whatever it is you are doing to calculate the varying row heights.

It has nothing to do with the labels themselves, or anything having to do with displaying text of varying heights. I've made tables whose rows vary in height with text of varying length displayed in labels or text drawn directly, and there's no such leakage.

You might want to look over the [section from my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_variable_row_heights) on this topic.

Comment: Text size is pre-calculated during data parsing to reduce the number of calculations during scrolling. So all I have to do in cell `layoutSubviews` is to set the label frame.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I somehow was setting the tableview frame height to the height of tableviews' content, so in fact all the cells were visible - thus not being reused.

Thanks @matt for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Uptick for figuring it out!